# Suds - Exception: (401, u'Unauthorized')

Tags: python, web-services, wsdl, suds

I'm trying to access a webservice with Python using suds. Here is my code:

```
# WSDL fails to import schema, import this and create client.
imp = Import('http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/')
imp.filter.add('http://api.daisycon.com/publisher/soap//program/')
d = ImportDoctor(imp)
encoded = base64.b64encode("%s:%s" % (username, password))
authenticationHeader = {
    "SOAPAction" : "http://api.daisycon.com/publisher/soap//program/#getSubscriptions",
    "Authorization" : "Basic %s" % encoded
}
client = suds.client.Client(self.url, headers = authenticationHeader, doctor=d)
```

However, it produces the following error when calling methods:

```
No handlers could be found for logger "suds.client"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\User\Documents\Crawler\src\Crawlers\Daisycon.py", line 39, in <module>
    Crawler().main()
  File "C:\Users\User\Documents\Crawler\src\Crawlers\Daisycon.py", line 37, in main
    print client.service.getSubscriptions()
  File "C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\suds\client.py", line 542, in __call__
    return client.invoke(args, kwargs)
  File "C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\suds\client.py", line 602, in invoke
    result = self.send(soapenv)
  File "C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\suds\client.py", line 649, in send
    result = self.failed(binding, e)
  File "C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\suds\client.py", line 708, in failed
    raise Exception((status, reason))
Exception: (401, u'Unauthorized')
```

I've tried adding the credentials every way I could find on the web. Nothing works. I'm 100% sure the credentials are right.

Another way I tried:

```
t = HttpAuthenticated(username=username,
                          password=password)
client = suds.client.Client(self.url, transport=t, doctor=d)
```

Which resulted in:

```
No handlers could be found for logger "suds.client"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\User\Documents\Crawler\src\Crawlers\Daisycon.py", line 35, in     <module>
    Crawler().main()
  File "C:\Users\User\Documents\Crawler\src\Crawlers\Daisycon.py", line 33, in main
    print client.service.getFeeds()
  File "C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\suds\client.py", line 542, in __call__
    return client.invoke(args, kwargs)
  File "C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\suds\client.py", line 602, in invoke
result = self.send(soapenv)
  File "C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\suds\client.py", line 649, in send
result = self.failed(binding, e)
  File "C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\suds\client.py", line 702, in failed
r, p = binding.get_fault(reply)
  File "C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\suds\bindings\binding.py", line 265, in get_fault
raise WebFault(p, faultroot)
suds.WebFault: Server raised fault: 'Need authorisation'
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe username/password are passed as a soapheaders? If so, you pass them like this:

```
from suds.sax.attribute import Attribute
from suds.sax.element import Element
...
usr = Element('USER').setText('username')
pwd = Element('PASSWORD').setText('password')
header_list = [usr, pwd]
reqsoap_attribute = Attribute('xsi:type', "xsd:string")
for param in header_list:
    param.append(reqsoap_attribute)
client.set_options(soapheaders=header_list)
```

This will add soap:Header section to the envelope, like:

```
<soap:Header>
    <USER xsi:type="xsd:string">username</USER>
    <PASSWORD xsi:type="xsd:string">password</PASSWORD>
</soap:Header>
```

Comment: And no luck with this way (include l/p to the headers portion directly)?: headers = {'username': 'username', 'password': 'password'}  and then pass the to Client. Also you can try this: client.set_options(headers={'username': 'username', 'password': 'password'})